# Return an array of integer when there is only one element using linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a requirement where I need to return an array for a selection that has only one value(in xml), as the data structure that will consume the data expects an array of integers(an array with one element) in its input.

This is how my XML file looks like

```
<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saw-sql="urn:saw-sql" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
    <xsd:complexType name="Row">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Column0" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;Financial Calendar&quot;.&quot;Month Year Short Name&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Financial Calendar&quot;.&quot;Month Year Short Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Financial Calendar" saw-sql:columnHeading="Month Year Short Name" saw-sql:isDoubleColumn="false" saw-sql:columnID="c29e370c0db340ad7" />
        <xsd:element name="Column1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula=" CASE WHEN &quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Current&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Level 5 Name&quot; ='Bill financing' THEN 'Deposits' WHEN &quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Current&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Level 5 Name&quot; IN ('Operating lease','Finance lease') THEN 'Lending' WHEN &quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Current&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Level 5 Name&quot; ='Hire purchase and equipment loans' THEN 'Fee Based' ELSE &quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Current&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Level 5 Name&quot; END" saw-sql:displayFormula=" CASE  WHEN &quot;GRD Product Current&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Level 5 Name&quot; = 'Bill financing' THEN 'Deposits' WHEN &quot;GRD Product Current&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Level 5 Name&quot; IN ('Operating lease', 'Finance lease') THEN 'Lending' WHEN &quot;GRD Product Current&quot;.&quot;GRD Product Level 5 Nam" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="GRD Product Current" saw-sql:columnHeading="Product" saw-sql:isDoubleColumn="false" saw-sql:columnID="c062984f028c318df" />
        <xsd:element name="Column2" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="double" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;Balances - Spot&quot;.&quot;Closing Balance&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Balances - Spot&quot;.&quot;Closing Balance&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="dimAggr" saw-sql:aggregationType="agg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Balances - Spot" saw-sql:columnHeading="Actual" saw-sql:isDoubleColumn="false" saw-sql:columnID="ca1e1d4f511a8bf93" />
        <xsd:element name="Column3" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="double" saw-sql:sqlFormula="(&quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;Balances - Spot&quot;.&quot;Closing Balance&quot;)*1.5" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Balances - Spot&quot;.&quot;Closing Balance&quot; * 1.5" saw-sql:aggregationRule="complex" saw-sql:aggregationType="agg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Balances - Spot" saw-sql:columnHeading="Forecast" saw-sql:isDoubleColumn="false" saw-sql:columnID="ca00747c911de130f" />
        <xsd:element name="Column4" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="double" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;Limits&quot;.&quot;Limit Amount&quot;*2" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Limits&quot;.&quot;Limit Amount&quot; * 2" saw-sql:aggregationRule="complex" saw-sql:aggregationType="agg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Balances - Spot" saw-sql:columnHeading="Target" saw-sql:isDoubleColumn="false" saw-sql:columnID="c88758b2e449f89d0" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
  <Row>
    <Column0>Sep-13</Column0>
    <Column1>Deposits</Column1>
    <Column2>330393232.5</Column2>
    <Column3>495589848.75</Column3>
    <Column4>703232974</Column4>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column0>Sep-13</Column0>
    <Column1>Fee Based</Column1>
    <Column2>111868709.42</Column2>
    <Column3>167803064.13</Column3>
    <Column4>703232974</Column4>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column0>Sep-13</Column0>
    <Column1>Lending</Column1>
    <Column2>18146873.33</Column2>
    <Column3>27220309.995</Column3>
    <Column4>703232974</Column4>
  </Row>
</rowset>
```

I was trying to do something like this to convert the value to an array of integers.

```
  var  resultSet = (xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Row").Select(result => new
            {
                MonthYearShortName = (DateTime) result.Element(ns + "Column0"),
                Product = (String) result.Element(ns + "Column1"),
                Actual = (decimal) result.Element(ns + "Column2"),
                Forecast = (decimal) result.Element(ns + "Column3"),
                Target = result.Elements(ns + "Column4").Select(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s.FirstNode)).ToArray()
            }));
```

I get an exception due to the conversion base `{System.SystemException} = {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XText' to type 'System.IConvertible'."}`

Comment: Let's think about that. Does your XML contain `Column4` elements at all? I can't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to `decimal` instead of using `Convert.ToDecimal` within `Select` method:

```
var resultSet = (xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Row").Select(result => new
{
    MonthYearShortName = (DateTime)result.Element(ns + "Column0"),
    Product = (String)result.Element(ns + "Column1"),
    Actual = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Column2"),
    Forecast = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Column3"),
    Target = result.Elements(ns + "Column4").Select(s => (decimal)s).ToArray()
}));
```

But, this makes sense only when you expect more than one `Column4` element to exist. Otherwise, you can just do following:

```
    Target = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Column4")
```

or to get `decimal[]` with just one value:

```
    Target = new []  { (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Column4") }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, are you expecting multiple Column4 entries? The definition doesn't make it look like that's the case, so this approach should work:

```
Target = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Column4")
```

Otherwise, if you do need an array add a `ToString` to the `FirstNode` call.

```
Target = result.Elements(ns + "Column4").Select(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s.FirstNode.ToString())).ToArray()
```

That said, it's not clear why you took a different route with the `FirstNode` approach. This should work instead and seems clearer to me:

```
Target = result.Elements(ns + "Column4").Select(s => (decimal)s).ToArray()
```

Comment: Edited the OP to include the namespace. I forgot about that. Now I get an exception.

Comment: @Navyseal I'm using the XML you provided and it works. If your XML is different than what's posted I can't tell what the issue is. My best guess is you might have a Row that's missing Column4, which would fail with the first approach I suggested using `Element`. One way around this is to cast to a nullable decimal, using `(decimal?)`. Alternately, the `Elements` approach would work, but means you're getting an array (or collection) back.

Comment: Well, I need to return the data as an array for Target as it had to be consumed elsewhere where the class expects an array for target.

I tried to use FirstNode assuming that I would be able to get the firstnode element.

When I try  this

Target = result.Elements(ns + "Column4").Select(s => (decimal)s).ToArray()

I am getting an empty target, basically



{ MonthYearShortName = {9/13/2014 12:00:00 AM}, Product = "Lending", Actual = 18146873.33, Forecast = 27220309.995, Target = {decimal[1]} }